# interfaces implemented by Typescript arrays

Tags: typescript, interface, ienumerable

In C#, arrays implement the `IEnumerable` interface, so I can write a function that accepts an `IEnumerable`, and callers can pass arrays or other classes (such as `List`) that implement the interface.

Is there a Typescript equivalent? I want to write a function that accepts array or any other collections that can be iterated, or generator functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`Iterable<T>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.6.3/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts#L50-L52), which relies on the presence of a method whose name is [the well-known symbol `Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) which implements the [iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols).  This is something that's part of ES2015 or later, so if you're using older runtimes you'll need to consider using the [`--downlevelIteration` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#new---downleveliteration) to target those runtimes.  Anyway, here's how you might use it:

```
function takeIterable<T>(iterable: Iterable<T>) {
    console.log("for-of");
    for (let t of iterable) {
        console.log(t);
    }

    console.log("array spread");
    const arr = [...iterable];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log(arr[i])
    }

    console.log("manually iterating")
    let iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
    for (let res = iterator.next(); !res.done; res = iterator.next()) {
        console.log(res.value);
    }

}
```

An `Iterable<T>` can be iterated with a [`for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into an array, or iterated directly using the iterator protocol mentioned above.

Then, in JavaScript ES2015+, arrays, strings, [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)s and [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)s, already implement the iterable protocol, or you can make your own:

```
takeIterable([1, 2, 3]); // arrays
takeIterable("hey"); // strings
takeIterable(new Set(["a", "b", "c", "a"])); // sets
takeIterable(new Map([["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]])); // maps

takeIterable({
    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        return {
            next() {
                const done = Math.random() > 0.8;
                return {
                    done,
                    value: done ? undefined : Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}); // custom iterable
// e.g., for-of 80 40 array spread 81 80 51 80 50 82 24 manually 28 45 51
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=39&ssc=29&pln=39&pc=42#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAhgawKYEkoYE4oBGANhgDwAqAfABQy4EkYBciO+RplVAlIgN4BYAFCIxiCAgDOcUgDpicAOY0ARMDh4AtHGCqeAbhHjEGvIhqkoyRLsT0OTPkNEnxksDPmKVUQ8fEAXxEAsQ8vDAVlNRQ8AgBPRCkABzwMFAATfSNXMOlrWPMAXkQAbTkKh0ZSAF0ckzMLK3tEEoAGAxayREKFDDAlKAALTpgAajHnULdw2UifGkLSmBqeaeDhadnvaNUAWxQwEBRiYkSqlFgB-Wnmi6hNVvsGTgxSgGV4vcJZOXvNGo0fy5UyPSwYaxpKRPf54ORgDAADygQM6AEIoXIMggMJ0oTCXg84QjkUCpiCTNt5tFMQA3E4gDDAkwbESs4SoTDsaoYGilACMABpEAAmYUAZlWnQA9NKenEUPEpCJOdgXkw1EMMPFsohZUkoHgYANlRz0GrHKQaAiAO6Id4QvmqFCqYWqQiuxCqCCe52qVaGPVyqQQ02q7mva0YO0AWRQyT5pT9wv5NWFSY9wpFabK3s9koDMrlB2SppV5ojGpcJg+Xx+xD+hIBQIE0xMaSgIDwSGrbj7JJR5L7w-c+UQ2IRTzjwzkBDA2L2LaoiDacgAHPUR8OO12e22t32JxhBfuDyZ6cRGawj4gAPyIcAZDDAY0YDKIVjToZyYCKTQ0L9Z0OBcWwAKkQfk2jaNYKTPDYz0QeDhyQsQNkCQN9QgEApAePZnktDARH1SIlDkYUzB0YBEDXNpEAAFlowpFSSVJ0nfNd+Wo2iAFZOJoxBuNotcRVFOjEAOI4TjOUU13o7iBP5EQgA)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is

```
private thing: object[]
```

or if you're defining an interface the syntax is

```
public interface IClassName {
  propName: object[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for C#'s `IEnumerable<T>`, read about *iterable* and *asyncIterable* symbols. A good starting point: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html

If you are looking for C#'s `yield`, read about *generator functions* (they return iterables or asyncIterables): https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/generators.html

If you are looking for a LINQ-like experience, take a look at this zero-dependency utility package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-iterable